# Navbar icon location in Twitter Bootstrap 3

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Currently working on a page for a project and I have my code for collapsing the navbar when the screen is adjusted for mobile. Everything works the way it should, my only problem is the position of the icon bar. Normally the icon bar is in the right hand corner of the page when it collapses, but is it possible to have it on the left hand side instead. I have searched around and I can find plenty of info on changing the icon image, at what point the navbar collapses, etc., but nothing on moving it to the other side of the screen.

This is just a basic navbar code with a collapse feature, but I need the icon on the left not the right.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>


    <link type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link type="text/css" href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Practice</a>
            </div>

            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="feature.html">Feature</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="tutorials" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Tutorials<b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Bootstrap Tutorials</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">PHP Tutorials</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Java Tutorials</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">CSS Tutorials</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Be sure to edit the question to include the code you are working with.

Answer (score 0):

Just a little bit of css does the magic:

```
.navbar-toggle {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/E72A3/)